# Kendo UI grid column resize issue in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have a kendo UI grid control and when I try to resize the grid columns I am able to see horizontal scroll bar below and see the overflowing columns when viewing the page in CHROME.

[image]

however in FIREFOX when I resize the columns only the table header values overflow the container and the records are adjusting inside the container and scroll bar is not visible.

[image]

One more issue I am facing is when I resize the browser the grouping header is expanding in both browsers.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an isolated runnable demo with this behavior? It should be caused by some custom JavaScript, CSS or HTML on the page.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it in kendo UI dojo but I was not able to reproduce it..

Comment: OK, so inspect your page and start removing parts until the cause is isolated.

Comment: Just double-checked a few of my Kendo grids in small FF windows and don't see either of the issues you are reporting. Some other code is probably involved.